# Can I use GitLab with centralize git repository server

Tags: git, repository, gitlab

My scenario is I have centralized Git repository server is running which is used by developers and they push their codes from local to centralize Git server.
Because GitLab has more features visualization,management like github so I am planing to use it with existing setup.

Is it possible to implement GitLab with git-server and keep up-to-date, every push over git-server will reflact on gitlab too ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add GitLab CE on your Git server, pointing it to your existing bare repo.

That way, you would push to the same server, and still benefit from GitLab features.

If you intend to mirror your git server pushes to `gitlab.com`, then you would need [`post-receive` hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-receive) on your bare repo in order to push them to their equivalent repos declared on gitlab.com.

Comment: 1st doubt is: to be more specific, you mean deploy gitlab over same centralize git-server and poin the gitlab storage to the git-server storage location..?
And 2nd doubt is: is every push from developer system to centralize git-server will reflect over GitLab too, will every repo will visible over gitlab ?

Comment: @anand 1/ Yes. 2/ Define "GitLab"? If it is your own GitLab-CE that you deploy on the same centralize git-server and point the gitlab storage to the git-server storage location, then yes. If it is gitlab.com, no, not without setting up post-receive hooks, and declaring those same repos at gitlab.com.

Comment: Thanks, Now I thing m closer to understand,my gitlab-ce is locally deployed   but first I need to workout on this because gitlab provides user based authentication and authorization. I will update you soon.

Comment: @anand Sure. This is the relevant section for referencing your repos: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/5af1fcd6f329858d757bab0d67cb50af6c820160/config/gitlab.yml.example#L466-476

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use existing git-server repo with gitlab and succeed to change the location of gitlab-storage path but on new location gitlab creates its own git-data/repositories directory  and then update repository followed by username.

Comment: @anand That is possible: you might have to move/rename your existing git repo folder (which has no incidence on the repo content and history itself)

Comment: Sir I have tried this too but found gitlab not recognize old repo and creates a username inside new location and under that directory store repo for belongs to that user. 
One solution I have found is copy git-repo to gitlab-repo under any user and update gitlab with gitlab-rake gitlab:import:repos. 
Here Problem will be old-repos permissions a lot of manual work and troubleshooting.